# STL vector inside the class access push

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl

What is the syntax to push integer into vector, which is inside Custothe class?

```
class Customer {
vector <int> loyalID;
}

int main {
Customer customer;

vector<Customer>customers;

customers.push_back(/*some integers to go into loyalID vector*/);
}
```

Comment: `customers` is a vector of `Customer`, not of `int`. You can push `Customer`s onto it, not `int`s. You can push `int`s onto `customer.loyalID` (or could if it weren't private). What, again, do you want to do?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Store uniqueID (say loyalty cards customer has) for each customer, and when I  access particular customer, show those uniqueID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loyalID` is a private field of `Customer`. Either make it public (not recommended), or add a public method:

```
class Customer {
  vector <int> loyalID;

  public:
  void addLoyalId(int id)
  {
    loyalID.push_back(id);
  }
}
```

Accessing loyal ids:

```
class Customer {
  vector <int> loyalID;

  public:
  void addLoyalId(int id)
  {
    loyalID.push_back(id);
  }

  std::vector<int>::iterator begin() const { return _loyalID.begin(); }
  std::vector<int>::iterator end() const { return _loyalID.end(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
Customer c;
c.addLoyalId(1);
c.addLoyalId(2);
c.addLoyalId(3);

for (auto&& id : c)
{
  std::cout << id << " ";
} // will print "1 2 3"
```

Comment: will it also work if I want to store multiple loyalID for each customer? If so, how could I access?

Answer (score 1):

Either make the vector public (which is not recommended) or write a public member function in the class:

```
void Customer::push_back(int i)
{
    loyalID.push_back(i);
}
```

In `main` once you have elements in `customers` you could write something like this:

```
customers[0].push_back(10);
```

Comment: `customers` is empty at this point; `customers[0]` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I have just provided the example of how the member function should be used. Made the clarification.